# Is it possible that my inner DONE ends my outer WHILE loop?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that has a while loop for reading file contents and a for loop to iterate over each row ( that the while loop reads).

However, the while loop only executes once, and when I comment out my inner for loop, it goes all the way to the end.

Is it possible that my inner done ends my outer while loop? And if so, how could I prevent this?

I also change my IFS variable during my for loop, but i change it back to the original with a "SAVEIFS" variable.

```
 while read -r  line ; do
    echo $line
        IFS=' '
        if [[ $line == *'.00'* ]]; then
         if [[ $line == *'+'* ]]; then
              # MANY FROM ONE
              read -r -a SplitValues <<< $line
                      DIFFSCOUNT= echo $line | grep -o "+" | wc -l

                      IFS='+'
                      # to split multiple
                      URL=${SplitValues[0]}
                      youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 ${SplitValues[0]}
          echo $DIFFSCOUNT
          for i in "${ALLDIFFS[@]}"
          do
           IFS=' '
           read -r -a ITLINE<<< $i

          IFS='>'
          read -r -a TITLE<<< $i
                      CLEANNAME=${TITLE[1]::-1}
                      ffmpeg -r 25 -i *.mp3 -ss ${iteratieLijn[0]} -to ${ITLINE[1]} -c copy -vb 20M $CLEANNAME.mp3
          cp $CLEANNAME.mp3 AllTogether/
          rm $CLEANNAME.mp3
         done
          rm *.mp3

         else
                      # SPECIFIC ONE
                      read -ra SplitValues <<< $line
                      youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 ${SplitValues[0]}
                      IFS='>' # > change delimiter for saving the name 
                      read -ra splitted<<< $line
                      CLEANNAme=${NaamGesplit[1]::-1}
         fi
        else
          echo "---Just One, plain--"
        fi
    fi
done < "${file}"
```

Comment: In cases like this you should first run your script through [ShellCheck – shell script analysis tool](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: There are some errors indicated Line 1:
     while read -r  line ; do
     ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this while loop. Fix to allow more checks.
                           ^-- SC1061: Couldn't find 'done' for this 'do'.

Comment: Line 40:
                fi
                ^-- SC1062: Expected 'done' matching previously mentioned 'do'.
                  ^-- SC1072: Unexpected keyword/token. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.

Comment: WOW thank you man, This was exactly a tool i was looking for! god bless you :-)

Comment: Please do not remove the code from the question after you have been asked to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I fixed the indenting on the code. It is important to do this as it will help you spot errors while you are writing the code.

After passing your code through [ShellCheck – shell script analysis tool](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and fixing the errors we get the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r  line
  do
  echo $line
  IFS=' '
  if [[ $line == *'.00'* ]]; then
    if [[ $line == *'+'* ]]; then
      # MANY FROM ONE
      read -r -a SplitValues <<< $line
      DIFFSCOUNT= echo $line | grep -o "+" | wc -l
      IFS='+'
      # to split multiple
      URL=${SplitValues[0]}
      youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 ${SplitValues[0]}
      echo $DIFFSCOUNT
      for i in "${ALLDIFFS[@]}"
      do
        IFS=' '
        read -r -a ITLINE<<< $i
        IFS='>'
        read -r -a TITLE<<< $i
        CLEANNAME=${TITLE[1]::-1}
        ffmpeg -r 25 -i *.mp3 -ss ${iteratieLijn[0]} -to ${ITLINE[1]} -c copy -vb 20M $CLEANNAME.mp3
        cp $CLEANNAME.mp3 AllTogether/
        rm $CLEANNAME.mp3
      done
      rm *.mp3
    else
      # SPECIFIC ONE
      read -ra SplitValues <<< $line
      youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 ${SplitValues[0]}
      IFS='>' # > change delimiter for saving the name 
      read -ra splitted<<< $line
      CLEANNAme=${NaamGesplit[1]::-1}
    fi
  else
    echo "---Just One, plain--"
  fi
  done < "${file}"
```

There are now no errors, but there are still many warnings you need to address:

```
$ shellcheck myscript
 
Line 2:
while read -r  line
^-- SC2095: ffmpeg may swallow stdin, preventing this loop from working properly.
 
Line 4:
  echo $line
       ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
  echo "$line"
 
Line 9:
      read -r -a SplitValues <<< $line
                                 ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
      read -r -a SplitValues <<< "$line"
 
Line 10:
      DIFFSCOUNT= echo $line | grep -o "+" | wc -l
                ^-- SC1007: Remove space after = if trying to assign a value (for empty string, use var='' ... ).
                       ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
      DIFFSCOUNT= echo "$line" | grep -o "+" | wc -l
 
Line 13:
      URL=${SplitValues[0]}
      ^-- SC2034: URL appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).
 
Line 14:
      youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 ${SplitValues[0]}
                                       ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
      youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 "${SplitValues[0]}"
 
Line 15:
      echo $DIFFSCOUNT
           ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
      echo "$DIFFSCOUNT"
 
Line 19:
        read -r -a ITLINE<<< $i
                             ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
        read -r -a ITLINE<<< "$i"
 
Line 21:
        read -r -a TITLE<<< $i
                            ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
        read -r -a TITLE<<< "$i"
 
Line 23:
        ffmpeg -r 25 -i *.mp3 -ss ${iteratieLijn[0]} -to ${ITLINE[1]} -c copy -vb 20M $CLEANNAME.mp3
        ^-- SC2095: Use ffmpeg -nostdin to prevent ffmpeg from swallowing stdin.
                        ^-- SC2035: Use ./*glob* or -- *glob* so names with dashes won't become options.
                                  ^-- SC2154: iteratieLijn is referenced but not assigned.
                                  ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
                                                         ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
>>                                                                                    ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086, apply all SC2095)
        ffmpeg -nostdin -r 25 -i *.mp3 -ss "${iteratieLijn[0]}" -to "${ITLINE[1]}" -c copy -vb 20M "$CLEANNAME".mp3
 
Line 24:
        cp $CLEANNAME.mp3 AllTogether/
           ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
        cp "$CLEANNAME".mp3 AllTogether/
 
Line 25:
        rm $CLEANNAME.mp3
           ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
        rm "$CLEANNAME".mp3
 
Line 27:
      rm *.mp3
         ^-- SC2035: Use ./*glob* or -- *glob* so names with dashes won't become options.
 
Line 30:
      read -ra SplitValues <<< $line
                               ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
      read -ra SplitValues <<< "$line"
 
Line 31:
      youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 ${SplitValues[0]}
                                       ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
      youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 "${SplitValues[0]}"
 
Line 33:
      read -ra splitted<<< $line
               ^-- SC2034: splitted appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).
                           ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
      read -ra splitted<<< "$line"
 
Line 34:
      CLEANNAme=${NaamGesplit[1]::-1}
      ^-- SC2034: CLEANNAme appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).
                ^-- SC2154: NaamGesplit is referenced but not assigned.
 
Line 39:
  done < "${file}"
          ^-- SC2154: file is referenced but not assigned (for output from commands, use "$(file ...)" ).

$
```